# data bus power consumption

Tags: vlsi, synthesis, asic, timing-analysis

In a design I have, I am using a memory arb (receiving mem requests from two masters) What are the pros and cons for each of the follwing:

1. use a mux for the read data of each master, so that if the memory is sending data to the second master, the bus connection to the master will not toggle

   pro - maybe save power consumption on the frozen data bus from the mem to the unused master? or does the addition of the mux spend more power?

   con - maybe create latencies for the timing calculations of the data
2. send the data from the mem to both masters every time it corresponds to one of the masters (along with a valid bit for each master)

   pro - better timing?

   con - more power consumption?

Answer (score 1):

The addition of demultiplexing logic increases power consumption and timing delays. There is no upside.

Without the demux, the memory is driving two sets of loads on the data bus, one set in each master.

With the demux, the memory is driving two sets of loads in the demux itself, plus the demux is driving one set of loads in one of the masters.

Comment: Thanks, Without demux - both masters busses shall toggle with every change of the other master's bus. does this not account for additional unrequired power consumption?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that without more details about the configuration of the busses on your chip. I was assuming we were talking about the read-data path from the memory to the two masters only. Also, since you tagged your question with [tag:vlsi] and [tag:asic], I'm assuming that we're talking about paths within a single chip, not about off-chip conenctions.

Comment: Hi, even in a single chip with data busses from a memory to 2 masters - what if the demux is located next to the memory, and the 2 masters are located at the other side of the chip, if the 2 busses are toggled every change of data it means that the interconnect of these 2 busses shall be loaded with data twice the number of times required

Comment: On the other hand, using a demux increases the power consumption because of the addition of the demux - but always keeps 1 bus quite (that can be across the entire chip).

Comment: Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well, OK, if the capacitance of the bus is a significant fraction of the total load capacitance, or if its resistance is a significant fraction of the driver's source impedance, there might be some advantage in keeping the bus "quiet" whenever possible. You would have to do some low-level simulation in order to see just how much benefit you would get, and balance that against the added complexity, time penalty and power consumption of the demux itself.

Comment: On average, half the bus lines will toggle on each memory read operation, and it's difficult to believe that the power dissipation associated with that could be at all significant in the context of the overall design.